# Авторизация с помощью ВКонтакте OAuth 2.0

Tags: авторизация, php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

На сайте будет только авторизация ВКонтакте. Я сделал, что пользователь авторизовывается, я получаю токен и записываю ID и токен в свою БД. Затем я ставлю session и пользователь считается залогиненым.

Однако представим, что пользователь потерял куки (новый браузер, устройство). Как не просить его снова разрешить приложению доступ каким-то данным? Т.е. когда он нажимает "Авторизоваться" и я вижу, что его токен у меня есть, я его авторизовываю.

На многих сайтах так и есть. Я нажимаю на кнопку ВК и меня перекидывает сразу в мой аккаунт, так как я уже авторизован.

Comment: > Как не просить его снова разрешить приложению доступ каким-то данным?

За это отвечает вк. Пользователь одобряет приложение один раз, при потере куки его все так же пересылает, просто пропускается вопрос о разрешении доступа.

Comment: @Fike и почему же тогда мне снова каждый раз приходится авторизовываться?

Comment: @inferus-vv, я бы в саппорт написал по этому поводу. В тот последний и единственный раз, когда с этим маялся, такого не было.

Comment: @Fike А может быть связано с тем, что это все на локалке?

Comment: @inferus-vv, теоретически да (если vk каким-то образом зачем-то проверяет redirect_uri и ожидаемо не находит), практически затык скорее всего в другом месте. По-хорошему в обычных настройках vk можно увидеть какие разрешения каким приложениям выданы.